# Why is this WPF border is showing around the column and not the StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to place a Border around a StackPanel like so:

```
<Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#009999" Background="Transparent" 
        BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
      <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,30,0,0">
           <!--Contents-->
      </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

For some reason, the border is appearing around the column that the StackPanel is in, not the StackPanel itself. I can change the margin of the border, but that doesn't hold up if the screen is resized. I also tried getting rid of the StackPanel margin but that made no difference. The StackPanel is the only object in this column.

Comment: set HorizontalAlignment="Center" on Border. by default it stretches

Comment: That did it! If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Border has default HorizontalAlignment equal to `Stretch`, so it takes full possible width.
Then StackPanel is centered inside the border because it has `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`.

set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` on Border. It will get width, equal to StackPanel width (plus Margin), and then will be centered

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you're setting the HorizontalAlignment to Center. Doing this will make the StackPanel size to whatever its content is.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the Border to stackpanel your problems will be fixed :)

here it is:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="350" Height="200">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Width="350" Height="200">
            <TextBlock>SomeText</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```